# How do I split a WPF window into two parts?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create an app that has a listbox on the left side (I'll style it to make it look good later).

On the right side, I want to have an area where I can add controls, etc

So the question is what do I need to do to split the Window into two unequal parts
(left side approx 350 pixels wide and height should be the entire window) and the remainder is for my "canvas."

Comment: Do not use canvas for the right side because canvas does not handling layout for its children and you are going to need it sooner or later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="350" /> <!-- Or Auto -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" />
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Or you could use a [DockPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx):

```
<DockPanel>
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="350" />
    <Canvas />
</DockPanel>
```

The benefit of the Grid is you have finer control over the layout and could allow the end user to dynamically resize the columns using a [GridSplitter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.aspx).

Comment: lol I was just doing that!! and you edited hehe. Oh well the posts already through now >.<

Edit: interesting, I didn't see this version of answer when I posted. It only came after my post. I guess you deleted your old answer with new one

Comment: @Maverik - Yeah, I thought about DockPanel second, probably since the tab order can be off when using it ;-)

Comment: I just assumed that won't be a problem since the OP seems to be in early stage of UI development where he just wants to see things happening instead of working out details. I'm sure he'll end up on grid closer to production time as he'll have pretty detailed idea by then of what exactly needs to go where in UI (and in what tab order)

Answer (score 4):

An alternate approach to CodeNaked's solution can be to use DockPanel where Canvas takes all space that is left automatically and you don't have to work out splits.

Of course this has the limitation of docking only to the four edges (with possibility of stacking up at edges) but I tend to prefer DockPanel when I'm making initial UI as they're rather quick and easy to setup compared to Grid setup which can get complex fairly quickly.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="350"/>
    <Canvas />
</DockPanel>
```